# Joining more table is reducing execution time

Tags: mysql, database, join, sqlperformance, sql-optimization

I was under the impression that the more number of tables you join in your query the more its execution time increases, but something really opposite is happening in my case.

Here is the query where I am joining two tables **task_group_attempt** and **task_group** -

```
select count(*) from (
select ga.id, ga.task_group_id from task_group_attempt ga 
where ga.started_on >= '2015-05-30 18:30:00' and ga.started_on < '2015-06-30 18:30:00'
) tab1 
inner join task_group tg on tg.id = tab1.task_group_id and tg.task_group_type_id != 6
```

The value it is returning is ***585856*** and the execution time is ***17.6 secs***.

For the table `task_group_attempt` **id** is the primary key and indexing has been done to the column **task_group_id**.

For the table `task_group` **id** is the primary key and indexing has been done to the column **task_group_type_id**.

Now the second query which is just the extension of the first one and here we are joining one more table named **task_attempt** -

```
select count(*) from (
select ga.id, ga.task_group_id from task_group_attempt ga 
where ga.started_on >= '2015-05-30 18:30:00' and ga.started_on < '2015-06-30 18:30:00'
) tab1 
inner join task_group tg on tg.id = tab1.task_group_id and tg.task_group_type_id != 6
inner join task_attempt ta on tab1.id = ta.task_group_attempt_id
```

The value it is returning is ***1109682*** and the execution time is ***7.88 secs***.

For the table `task_attempt` indexing has been done to the column **task_group_attempt_id**.

I have checked it multiple times and every time the query execution time is almost or close to the above mentioned time.

**ADDITION INFO -**

Number of rows in `task_group_attempt` is 8565011 
Number of rows in `task_group` is 1057 
Number of rows in `task_attempt` is 15156598

It would be really helpful is somebody can help me understand how is this possible?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you run the queries in the opposite order? In other words, run the 3-join query first, then the 2-join query. Mysql caching can make a significant difference in run times.

Comment: You'll have to show the query plans for anyone to be able to say anything.

Comment: @Chris Lear that is exactly what I thought, may be because of the MySql caching the 3-join query is running fast. But that is not true, even running it in reverse order I see the same output.